Why smart contract calls transferFrom ERC721 instead of ERC20?
I create project using Solidity, Hardhat for testing deploying, and hardhat tracer for debugging? I have smart contract that inherits ERC721Holder from @openzeppelin library. On this smart contract I tries to call transferFrom from ERC20 contracts.
import {ERC721Holder} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/utils/ERC721Holder.sol";
import {IERC721} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

import {IOffer} from "./IOffer.sol";

import {Ownable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721Holder, Ownable {

    // ...

    address constant WETH_ADDRESS = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
  
    constructor(
        address _withdrawalSCAddress,
        address initialOwner,
        uint16 _commissionPercent
    ) payable Ownable(initialOwner) {
        withdrawalSCAddress = _withdrawalSCAddress;

        commissionPercent = _commissionPercent;
    }

    function approveOffer(uint256 _offerId) public payable {
        
        OfferInfo memory offerInfo = offers[_offerId];
        NFTSaleInfo memory nftSaleInfo = nftSales[offerInfo.saleId];

        uint256 priceOfPart = (nftSaleInfo.price * offerInfo.percentPart) / 100;

        uint256 commission = getCommissionAmount(priceOfPart);

        if (nftSaleInfo.isWithdrawed) revert AlreadyBought();
        if (msg.value == commission)
            revert NotCorrectCommission(msg.value, commission);
        
        
        // Here error occured
        // ======================
        // transfer WETH (commission from buyer)
        IERC20(WETH_ADDRESS).transferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            nftSaleInfo.sellerAddress,
            priceOfPart
        );
        IERC20(WETH_ADDRESS).transferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            withdrawalSCAddress,
            commission
        );
        // ======================

        // transfer native ETH (commission from seller)
        payable(withdrawalSCAddress).transfer(commission);

        // update state
        nftSales[offerInfo.saleId].isWithdrawed = true;

        IOffer(nftSaleInfo.nftAddress).splitNFT(
            nftSaleInfo.nftId,
            nftSaleInfo.percentPart,
            msg.sender,
            nftSaleInfo.sellerAddress
        );

        emit OfferApproved(_offerId, offerInfo.saleId);
    }

    // ...

}

When I test this function hardhat tracer shows that IERC20(WETH_ADDRESS).transferFrom calls from ERC721 instead ERC20 (third argument is displayed as tokenId instead value) and gives next error:
Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2)
    at NFTMarketplace.approveOffer (contracts/NFTMarketplace.sol:311)
    at EdrProviderWrapper.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:433:41)
    at async TracerWrapper.request (node_modules\hardhat-tracer\src\wrapper.ts:66:16)
    at async HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:125:18)
    at async send (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:313:20)
    at async Proxy.approveOffer (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:352:16)


In my test I check that user have enough tokens and sufficient allowance for this contract
Is anyone knows how resolve this issue?

Before calling transferFrom function, you've to go to the corresponding ERC20 token contract (i.e., WETH contract in your case) and call the approve function by passing in the address of your NFTMarketplace contract as spender and the sum of priceOfPart and commission as amount, so as to approve the NFTMarketplace contract to transfer the required amount of WETH token on your (or msg.sender) behalf.

Yes, I approved NFTMarketplace from msg.sender
But problem remains

I want to understand why hardhat-tracer shows me transferFrom of ERC721 instead ERC20


The stack tracer (in the screenshot that you've attached) is showing the calling of transferFrom of ERC20 or WETH only. As, you can see it's showing it as NFTMarketplace(ADDRESS).approveOffer() -> WETH(ADDRESS).transferFrom().

Third argument of transferFrom displayed as tokenId instead value

Oh okay. I’ve just noticed that. Can you add your imports too?

Also, if you can share a gist, having your contract code (minimal reproducible), then I can try to debug that on my end.

Add imports
It's very big contract

But thanks for response
